# Create a new folder using bash without mkdir command

Tags: bash, mkdir

i'm creating a small shell script, and i want to know if is there a builtin command to create a new folder without using the mkdir command.
I googled it but i wasn't able to find a way to do that.

I dont have any specific motivation or restriction to do that, is more a curiosity about the builtin commands on bash.

I imagine is somenthing like the
touch file => > file

Regars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We generally don't play games here and artificially restrict what can and can't be used just for the fun of it. The builtin commands are

> bash,  :,  .,  [, alias, bg, bind, break, builtin, caller, cd, command, compgen, complete, com-
>          popt, continue, declare, dirs, disown, echo, enable, eval, exec, exit, export, false,  fc,  fg,
>          getopts,  hash,  help,  history,  jobs, kill, let, local, logout, mapfile, popd, printf, pushd,
>          pwd, read, readonly, return, set, shift, shopt, source, suspend, test, times, trap, true, type,
>          typeset, ulimit, umask, unalias, unset, wait

You can find out more about them using `man builtins`.

Comment: It is useful to know alternatives for non-builtins such as `mkdir` or `ls` when working on a broken system. By the way, `echo *` is the substitute for `ls`.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a 'builtins' solution (like touch is not a builtin), but it is a bash friendly solution.

Since this is a script, you imply planning.  With this in mind, you create a directory, which you plan to use when the need arises within your script.  When you need a new, empty directory, you will use the 'cp -r' command.

You would create a directory: `/tmp/seed`

In your script you need a directory called blue2013.

```
cp -r /tmp/seed ./blue123
```

Comment: If you want to make sure the directory stays empty so the recursive copy only copies the directory, `chmod -w /tmp/seed` Also, you may want to put your seed directory somewhere else so it doesn't get automatically deleted.